# Contact Report Filter: How to include Street Address?

Tags: civireport

I'm trying to create a contact report (summary) and Street Address is not among the filters. Is there a way to include it?

Comment: Update: What I did is edit the "sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form.php" and added the street address. Is this correct and acceptable? Thanks!         'street_address' => array(
          'title' => ts('Street Address'),
          'name' => 'street_address',
          'operator' => 'like',
        ),

Answer (score 1):

What version of Civi are you on? Look for Constituent Summary in Reports. And install Eileen's Extended Report extension [here](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) and take a look at the Constituent Report (Summary).

Comment: Hi, Thanks! Just did and I'm looking at "Flexible Contact Report". However, the custom fields I created do not appear on the columns tab. Unlike in the Constituent Report (Summary). civiCRM v.4.6.6.

Comment: So to add custom fields to a report might require creating your own extension, perhaps using Eileen's as the base and adding on to that - or starting from scratch. See http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+an+Extension. You may get what you want by creating a new Profile with the fields you need and making that a Search View that you can then print out.